# Understanding Forward Secrecy

Tags: cryptography, certificate, private-key

Recently, I was pointed to a [post](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.in/2011/11/protecting-data-for-long-term-with.html) from 2011 by a friend, which described Google's move towards forward secrecy. From what I understand, the essence of forward secrecy seems to lie in the fact that the private keys are not kept in persistant storage.

I have various doubts about how something like this could be implemented.

1. What if the server goes down without warning - do the key pairs have to be regenerated? Does the public key have to be signed again to create another certificate?
2. Could someone point me to posts/pdfs where the implementation of something like this is described. Suggested reading resources?
3. Are you aware of anyone else that has implemented forward secrecy? Have you tried something similar at your workplace?

Thanks!

Comment: See Also [What should I know before configuring Perfect Forward Secrecy](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/7690/396)

Comment: Perfect forward secrecy doesn't have to mean the key is never persisted, it happens when you destroy all keys that encrypt the data.

Answer (score 4):

In **Forward Secrecy**, there are still long-term keys. The only implication is, that the compromisation of a long-term key will not allow an attacker to compromise temporary session keys, when the long-term key has changed. This means that a long-term key **must not** be derived from another (older) key.

[Here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~itkis/pap/forward-secure-survey.pdf) is a good survey on this topic.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy):

- PFS is an optional feature in IPsec (RFC 2412).
- SSH.
- Off-the-Record Messaging, a cryptography protocol and library for many instant messaging clients, provides perfect forward secrecy as well as deniable encryption.
- In theory, Transport Layer Security can choose appropriate ciphers since SSLv3, but in everyday practice many implementations refuse to offer PFS or only provide it with very low encryption grade.

Answer (score 1):

In TLS and many other protocols forward secrecy is provided through the [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie_hellman) (DH) algorithm. Vanilla DH is rather simple and provides perfect forward secrecy if the exponents are randomly generated each time, but provides no authentication. Therefore in TLS it is using in combination with a signature algorithm, usually RSA.

TLS provides many ciphersuites that support PFS and many that do not. Most TLS clients support PFS but many servers do not, because it is thought that PFS takes too much CPU.

Comment: I thought you needed "ephemeral DH" (edh), and not just DH for forward  secrecy.  See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/how-can-i-use-ssl-tls-with-perfect-forward-secrecy